# Spring Security defaultsuccessurl for different roles?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have three different roles, But I don't know how to add different pages for each role after login, is that possible to add something to redirect each role to its page?
I'm using thymeleaf and spring security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include different containt in page for diffenet roles

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    Content for administrators
</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
    Content for users
</div>
```

For example, it can be different fragments for each role

```
<div th:include="pages/welcome :: welcome_admin" sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')></div> 

<div th:include="pages/welcome :: welcome_user" sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')></div>
```

Comment: I have another question, can I communicate with you or I have to post it?

Comment: if it's not big question, write just here, otherwise better post it as a question

Comment: I put every js and css content in static folder, anyone can access that without a controller, how can I make it private? @Elizabeth

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer (may be not right understand what do you mean). Post it as a question, someone will help. @Hama Saadwn